# Obtain list of divisors from a list of primes factors in Python

Tags: python, math

I have created a function whose input is a natural number `n` and its output is a `list` of its prime factors. For example, for the input `100`, it returns `[2, 2, 5, 5]`.

I would like to create a function that

1. transforms the `list` of my output into a neater one, where the same prime factors are combined (in my list the prime factors are ordered in non-decreasing order) into a power. In the above example,  `[2^2, 5^2]`.
2. returns a `list` of the divisors of `n` from this new list.

In particular, once I have the `list` with the powers, 
 `[p_1^{n_1},..., p^_k{n_k} ]`

I'd like to iterate to obtain all the multiples as `p_1^{a_1}* ... *p^_k{a_k}`,
where the `a_i` are no negative and less or equal than the `n_i`.

Comment: *I am sorry about the format of the math lines*. Don't be sorry, fix them.

Comment: can you send me a link on how to include LaTeX in here?

Comment: You cannot include LaTex on stackoverflow. It's a shame, but that's the truth. Instead, provide your best attempt to approximate the notation in a clear manner. In any event, you need to show an attempt to solve the problem on your own, or explain the specific issue preventing you from making any progress.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
from collections import Counter


def neatify(numbers):
    return [a ** b for a, b in Counter(numbers).items()]


def divisors(n, divisors):
    return [n // d for d in divisors]
```

Use it like `divisors(60, neatify([60, 2, 2, 5]))`

Comment: Thanks, although I am afraid the second part won't list all the multiples of the number, I have explained a bit further on my comment to Eric

Answer (score 1):

For #1, if you create a defaultdict where the key is the number, and the value is the number of times it appears, you should be able to accomplish your goal.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def concat_factors(factors):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for factor in factors:
        d[factor] += 1
    return [k ** v for k, v in d.items()]

>>>prime_factors = [2, 2, 5, 5]
...concat_factors(prime_factors)
[4, 25]
```

For #2, it is very hard to ascertain what you are trying to do. You may want to provide some additional detail or clarification.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know about the collections library. For the second part, once I have the dictionary with the prime factors and their power, for example, for n=200 that would be [(2, 3), (5, 2)] the I would need to do two for loops, the first one for the power of 2, i.e. 3 and the second for the powers of 5, i.e. 2, and then set a list with the multiples. The entries added to the list are m= 2^i 5^j where i=0,1,2,3 and j=0,1,2